# codeigniter jquery not working

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have included files in codeigniter webpage like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='<?= base_url() ?>css/unofficialchannels/style.css' />
<script type="text/javascript" src='<?= base_url() ?>js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src='<?= base_url() ?>js/jquery.tweetable.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src='<?= base_url() ?>js/javascript.js'></script>
```

I have a function in javascript.js file like this:

```
$(function () {
  alert('It works!');
});
```

I also tried a function like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert('It works!');
});
```

But it doesn't work, i don't get alert. Anybody has any ideas?

Comment: where is your css folder situated

Comment: Both css and js folder are in public_html folder, which is root. Css works perfectly, i have problem only with javascript. Actually with jquery. If i add `alert('it works');` to `javascript.js` without jquery function, i get alert.

Comment: Are you getting any output or errors in Firebug/your favourite js debugging tool?

Comment: also check in the firebug if the jquery file is loaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it works now. I had some king of a problem with jquery file. I downloaded it from jquery.com and uploaded it again. It works ok now.

Answer (score 0):

Your folder structure should be like this

```
application/
system/
assets/css
assets/js
assets/images
```

And now

in your config.php

```
$config['assets'] = $config['base_url'] . 'assets/';
```

And now in your view do this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='<?php echo $assets?>css/unofficialchannels/style.css' />
<script type="text/javascript" src='<?php echo $assets?>js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src='<?php echo $assets?>js/jquery.tweetable.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src='<?php echo $assets?>js/javascript.js'></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the single quotes with double quotes in the src/href attributes, so

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='<?= base_url() ?>js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js'></script>
```

would become

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?= base_url() ?>js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
```

And make sure, your js and css directories are in the same place where your CodeIgniter files are.

Your folder should look something like:

```
application/
system/
tmp/
css/
js/
index.php
license.txt
```

Comment: I changed quotes, but it doesn't help. Folder structure is exactly as yours.

Answer (score 0):

just for info base_url() function receives an optional arg which is appended to the base_url itself so for example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='<?= base_url(); ?>js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js'></script>
```

should be written as:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='<?= base_url("js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"); ?>'></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

if anyone searching for the answer in 2021. I downloaded the uncompressed, development jQuery form Jquery website and didn't used minified(.min) version. It worked.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src='<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/jquery-3.6.0.js'></script>
```